# CodeIgniter 404 page routes on SuSe

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, suse

I'm trying to upload my web to a server, and this is Suse 13. I've got an Apache2.4 installed and PHP 5.6. In Windows the same web is working great, but not on Suse. If I write on the direction bar http://myip/myweb/index.php/ControllerName/MethodName it works, but the routing is not working.

I've got my controller file with a capital letter Controller.php, inside, the class name is Controller and the method is "method", in lower case. In routes.php I've got:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'controller';
$route['bar/foo'] = 'controller/method';
```

My config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://myip/myweb/';
$config['index_page'] = ''; //I can see the index page correctly
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

And finally, my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
ServerSignature Off

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?
 </IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE model/vnd.collada+xml
# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

I need help, I don't know what to do...

Thank you!

EDIT:

Enabled modules in apache:

```
actions alias auth_basic authn_file authz_host authz_groupfile authz_user autoindex cgi dir env expires include log_config mime negotiation setenvif ssl socache_shmcb userdir php5 reqtimeout authn_core authz_core version man rewrite
```

Answer (score 0):

People, if you are wondering what the f*** is wrong, you have to know that in the Apache configuration file you have to add AllowOverride All!!!

http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/mod_rewrite-on-suse/